# Difference between Contusion, Haemorrage and Hematoma?

Tags: blood, muscle, hematology, bruising-bruise

As per wikipedia these are the definitions:

A contusion, commonly known as a bruise, is a type of hematoma of tissue[1] in which capillaries and sometimes venules are damaged by trauma, allowing blood to seep, hemorrhage, or extravasate into the surrounding interstitial tissues.
[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruise)

A hematoma (US spelling) or haematoma (UK spelling) is a localized collection of blood outside the blood vessels, due to either disease or trauma including injury or surgery[1] and may involve blood continuing to seep from broken capillaries. [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematoma)

Bleeding, also known as hemorrhaging or haemorrhaging, is blood escaping from the circulatory system.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding)

So, is contusion a hematoma due to trauma? Is haemorrhage a technical term for bleeding (even simple ones)?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE! Please expand a bit on your previous research and edit the question with the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help) of [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).